# Checking raster value type in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster

I naively assumed that the rasterType() function would give me the data value type for the raster (i.e. integer or float), but it just tells you whether it's a singleband or multiband raster.

Is there a function in QGIS that I can use to check whether the input raster to a script is integer or float (similar to what you get out of the VALUETYPE in the GetRasterProperties function in ArcGIS)?

Basically need to run a check so that if the input isn't an integer raster it should throw an exception and exit.

ArcPy snippet I am trying to convert:

```
EvidenceLayer = parameters[0].valueAsText
    valuetype = gp.GetRasterProperties (EvidenceLayer, 'VALUETYPE')
    #if valuetype not integer:
    if valuetype > 8:  
        gp.adderror('Not an integer-type raster')
        raise ErrorExit
```

Comment: The type is associated with the band https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html#fetching-a-raster-band might help. The return value should be in the enum GDALDataType: One of Byte, UInt16, Int16, UInt32, Int32, Float32, Float64, and the complex types CInt16, CInt32, CFloat32, and CFloat64 referenced https://gdal.org/user/raster_data_model.html#raster-data-model is that what you're after? It would help if you could include some of your code to build on to make a good answer.

Comment: I have added the ArcPy snippet that I am trying to convert to an equivalent in QGIS. The code needs to have a classified raster as input to do what it needs to do.

I think the GdalDataType is what I'm after though. Thank you!